# How to string split numbers in python

Tags: python, regex, split

This is what I have, but I know it is incorrect and I'm not sure what to change

```
print '0.4066145E-07-0.3677403'.split('E+(\-\d{2})', 1 )
```

I'm looking to get:

```
['0.4066145E-07','-0.3677403']
```

or more generally I just want to split up these numbers.

```
['######E-##','#########']
```

Also what if there is an exponent in the second number?

```
['######E-##','#######E-##']
```

Comment: Just for curiosity...are you here trying to extract *scientific notation of a floating numbers* in your strings?

Comment: I just had output that was running into one another and therefore creating errors.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can try with:

```
(?<=E-\d\d)(?=-\d+.)
```

[DEMO](https://regex101.com/r/jO1nC2/2)

Comment: Thank you! Works perfectly and that site you linked to is great. Definitely going to be using that more.